# NextJS App Router and MongoDB - How to fetch data

Tags: mongodb, next.js, next.js13

I have a NextJS project which I'm migrating to the new App Router format.

The problem is that whenever the route changes to a page that needs to fetch data (from MongoDB), the browser seems to freeze for some seconds, and the **loading.tsx** file I set up only seems to appear after the data fetching is done, for half a second while the components load, I suppose.

I have all my MongoDB operations in TS files inside an `utils` folder which I'm exporting to the `app` pages.

The pages are server-only, and I'm simply declaring the data and then providing it as props to my React components, which are declared as `client only`.

Example:

```js
import { getAppointments, preloadAppointments } from "@util/AppointmentService";
import AppointmentList from "src/components";

export default async function AppointmentListPage(){
 preloadAppointments();
 const appointments = JSON.parse(
  JSON.stringify(await getAppointments())
 );    
 return(
  <AppointmentList appointments={appointments}/>
 )
}
```

Is this the wrong way of doing it? Should I be making `api` routes instead and use `fetch` with a fully client-side page?

Let me know your thoughts!